# ¿Como seleccionar varias filas en Data Table jQuery y obtener un dato de cada fila seleccionada?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Como se puede seleccionar varias filas de un Data Table jQuery, y obtener los datos de la primera columna de cada fila seleccionada????

Comment: Bienvenido SergioDen, te invito a que pases por [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), y edites tu pregunta mostrando ¿que has intentado? y ¿que errores te salen? así brindas una mejor pregunta y aumentas la calidad del sitio, también ayudaras a otros a que te den una mejor respuesta acorde a tu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo que viene en la pagina de [Datatables.net](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    var dato = "";
    
    //para seleccionar una opcion
    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
            dato = "";
            console.log(dato);
        }
        else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            dato = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
            console.log(dato);
        }
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Para múltiples opciones se usaría el siguiente fragmento en lugar del código de seleccionar una opción, este código lo puedes encontrar en los [ejemplos de datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html).

```
//multiples opciones
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    dato = ", " + $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
    console.log(dato);
} );
```

Comment: Funciona, al 100%, te lo agradezco!!!!